# Find the matrix X such that $A\cdot X = X\cdot A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am working at some linear transformations and I need to know if it is possible given a square real matrix $A$, to find a real square invertible matrix $X$ such that 
$$ X^{-1} \cdot A \cdot X = A^T$$ where $A^T$ means the transposed of $A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix and its transpose have the same characteristic polynomial, minimal polynomial and elementary divisors etc. so they have the same Jordan normal form, hence are similar.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your attention! Can you give some hints about a simple way of finding $X$? Should we say $A = P_1^{-1}\cdot J\cdot P_1$ and $A^T = P_2^{-1}\cdot J\cdot P_2$ hence $P_1\cdot A \cdot P_1^{-1} = P_2\cdot A^T\cdot P_2^{-1} = J $ and then $X^{-1} = P_2^{-1}\cdot P_1$? Is there any other simpler way of finding $X$?

Comment: I don't know whether a simple method exists. Going through the Jordan normal form certainly isn't practical.

Answer (score 2):

We assume that $A$ is real. Of course, we do not look for the Jordan forms of $A,A^T$ (because, practically, we cannot find them when $n\geq 5$).

The solution is in the OP's title; it suffices to solve the LINEAR equation $AX=XA^T$;

EDIT. (Answer to C Marius). The set $V$ of the solution is a vector space that has same dimension as the vector space of the matrices that commute with $A$ (in particular, its dimension $k$ is $\geq n$). Any software working on the Sylvester equation gives to you (with complexity $O(n^3)$) a basis of $V$: $(X_i)_i$. Since $A,A^T$ are similar over $\mathbb{R}$, we know that  among the  $\sum_i a_i X_i\in V$, there exists at least an invertible matrix.

We assume that each $a_i$ follows an absolutely continuous distribution law of probability (for example the normal law on $\mathbb{R}$ or the uniform law on $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$) and that these previous laws are independent..

$\textbf{Proposition}$. If we randomly choose the $(a_i)$, then we obtain an invertible solution with probability $1$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. Consider the function $f:a=(a_i)_i\in\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \det(\sum_i a_iX_i)$. There is $a$ s.t. $f(a)\not= 0$; then $f^{-1}(0)$ is a Zariski closed proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$. Thus $\{a;f(a)\not= 0\}$ is a Zariski open dense Zariski subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and we are done.

Comment: That is probably the best practical method. You use the theoretical existence proof  to ascertain that there is an invertible solution, and just try to find it by solving the $n^2$ by $n^2$ system $AX=XA^T$.

Comment: @Kusma ; in fact the system $AX-XA^T=0$ is a Sylvester equation. There are softwares that do the job quickly in $O(n^3)$ (and not in $O(n^6)$).

Comment: Sir, thank for your attention! It is indeed a Sylvester equation $A\cdot X + X\cdot B = C $ with $B = -A^T$ and $C = 0_{n\times n}$ However, because the spectra of $A$ and $-B = A^T$ are identical, the solution is not unique right?

Comment: You did not read carefully my answer; cf. my edit which gives more details.

Answer (score 0):

As loup blanc mentioned that it's a Sylvester equation, here is an addendum utilizing [vec operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products):

\begin{align}
AX-XA^T = 0 \\
AXI - I X A^T = 0\\
\textrm{vec} \left( AXI \right) - \textrm{vec} \left(I X A^T \right) = 0\\
\left(I \otimes A\right)\textrm{vec}\left(X\right) -  \left(A \otimes I\right)\textrm{vec}\left(X\right) = 0\\
\left(I \otimes A - A \otimes I\right)\textrm{vec}\left(X\right) = 0  
\end{align}

Then one can find a solution which lies in the nullspace of $\left(I \otimes A - A \otimes I\right)$.